# How to parse the post_meta data using php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to parse the meta value of post in wordpress db using deserialize function but it returns an error like follows

> **Notice**:  unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 562 of 2954 bytes in **/home/shyampri/public_html/shopchalo.in/word.php** on line  **45**

Comment: There is an error in the data you are giving the function. Where are you getting it from? Also this has nothing to do with JSON

Comment: Thank you Toby. I am fetching the data from database using sql query, and storing into one variable $a. Using $a into unserialize function.

Comment: @Mad It's better to update your question to add the code you're using, so we can see it in context with the error.